# How to build IOS apps in flutter in windows

Tags: ios, flutter

I want to develop a application for for my company. I'm using flutter to build it for both android and IOS platform. But I have only windows machine, so I'm only able to build it for Android. Can I build(generate apk) IOS flutter apps in windows machine ?

if yes please explain it well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can develop the UI on android itself. However, you need OSX to run an Iphone Simulator. An alternative would be to use a virtual machine with OSX installed. It is not recommended though.

Also, for IOS the build is different. It is not as simple as generating an apk and installing it on your phone. You will need itunes and a legit account to run it.

See more [here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-test-your-flutter-ios-app-on-your-ios-device-75924bfd75a8)